# Dynamically create rows with select box select multiple values in mysql using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="lobrows">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Reson</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]" required="required">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($ob->showDataall("select * from tblname") as $value) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $value['field_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['field']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Service </label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service" multiple="multiple">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">List 1</option>
                    <option value="2">List 2</option>
                    <option value="3">List 3</option>
                    <option value="4">List 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Name </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="pull-right" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;add</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var i=$('.mrbtm').length+1;
            $('#lobrows').append('<div class="mrbtm"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-4"><label>Reson </label><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="reson[]"><option>--Select--</option><?php foreach($ob->showDataall("select * from tblname") as $value){?><option value="<?php echo $value['field_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['field']; ?></option><?php }?></select></div><div class="col-sm-4"><label>Service </label><select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="service[]" id="service'+i+'" multiple="multiple"><option>--Select--</option><option value="1">List 1</option><option value="2">List 2</option><option value="3">List 3</option><option value="4">List 4</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-4"><label>Name </label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></div></div><a href="#" class="pull-right remove"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</a><br /></div>');
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;
        });
    });
</script>
```

If i click add button new row created in each row there is a select box inside that i have so many options i should have to choose multiple options at a time and it should have to save on database

**Here is my php code**

```
<?php
foreach ($reson as $id => $value) {
    $reson = ($reson[$id]);
    $namep = ($name[$id]);
    $rsid = $ob->insert_data('tbl_reson',array("reson" => $reson, "name" => $namep), true);
    foreach ($service as $ii => $valu) {
        $r_service = ($service[$ii]);
        $ob->insert_data('tbl_service',array("reson_id" => $rsid, "service" => $r_service));
    }
}
?>
```

How to solve this problem

I need to save the values in different table first table is tbl_reson and second table is tbl_service, reson and name is inserted in first table and the service is inserted in second table

Comment: Can you explain your question more in details

Answer (score -1):

To create a dynamic select option menu using Ajax and PHP it takes only three steps:-
Make a PHP file and define markup and script for select option menu
Make a CSS file and define styling for select option menu
Connect to the database and Send data

Step 1.Make A PHP file and define markup and script for select option menu
We make a PHP file and save it with a name select.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'fetch_data.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP</p>
<center>
<div id="select_box">
 <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
  <option>Select state</option>
  <?php
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
  mysql_select_db('demo');

  $select=mysql_query("select state from places group by state");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
   echo "<option>".$row['state']."</option>";
  }
 ?>
 </select>

 <select id="new_select">
 </select>
   
</div>     
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

In this step we get the states from our places table and insert in our first select option menu then we use onchange event which call the fetch_select(); function which passes an ajax request to fetch_data.php and gets the result and insert in our second select option menu

Step 2.Make a CSS file and define styling for select option menu
We make a CSS file and save it with name select_style.css

```css
body
{
 background-color:#E6E6E6;
 font-family:helvetica;
}
#heading
{
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:150px;
 font-size:30px;
 color:blue;
}
#select_box
{
 width:500px;
 background-color:#819FF7;
 padding:10px;
 height:200px;
 border-radius:5px;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px grey;
}
select
{
 width:400px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid #BDBDBD;
 margin-top:20px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:grey;
 border-radius:5px;
}
```

Step 3.Connect to the database and Send data
We make a PHP file save it with a name fetch_data.php which is used to connect and fetch data and then send data to select.php file on ajax request.

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
 $host = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
 mysql_select_db('demo');

 $state = $_POST['get_option'];
 $find=mysql_query("select city from places where state='$state'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
 {
  echo "<option>".$row['city']."</option>";
 }
 exit;
}
?>
```